# Windows del command not working?

Tags: windows, cmd.exe

I'm trying to delete a large directory.  I run the delete (del /f node_modules), and it appears to work, but then the directory is still there... (When I try to delete it from the file explorer, it usually gives me some flavor of "you need admin permissions" or "can't delete because file is in use" or it just takes forever.)

Here's my question:  what causes the del command to appear to work, but not actually work?  I'd expect some output indicating the directory wasn't deleted.

[Picture of the command used, and the result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XgSTK.png)  [Another example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yTyjv.png)

Comment: Does Shift+Delete work? Try skipping the Recycle Bin.

Comment: Provide a screenshot of the ACL for the folder in question.  If you are getting an error indicating a permission problem it sounds like you don't have the required permissions to delete it.  It does not matter if you are an Administrator, if you don't currently have the required permissions, you would get a permission error.  Please do not submit a comment in response to this comment.  Instead, edit your question with the information required to answer your question.

Comment: There's no error in the output.  The command appears to complete.  Also thanks for that shift+delete tip, although I need to do this programmatically, as part of a script.

Comment: @JohnnyKumpf - You said in your question there was an error.  Please provide the exact error and that screenshot I requested.  Your question cannot be answered without this information.

Comment: My goal isn't to delete it from the file explorer.  I want to force a delete from the command line.  I'm not sure exactly which errors produce what behavior; what I really want to know is what are the possible causes for the behavior I'm observing in the cmd: namely that the del command appears to work, but the directory is still there afterwards.

Comment: Why won't you provide the ACL for the folder?  It seems you are avoiding providing that information on purpose.

Comment: For one thing, I'm not totally sure how to get it.  Another is I already deleted the directory with shift+delete, so I'm not sure I can.  But mostly, I don't care about this particular situation.  I just want to know what criteria can lead to the behavior where the del command appears to work and doesn't.  Is there something you're going to look for in the control list that causes the del command to look like it completed, when it didn't?  If so, just tell me that generally, because again, I don't really care about this specific case.  What issue(s) cause(s) this symptom, in general?

Comment: The ACL can be viewed by viewing the properties of the folder.  **What issue(s) cause(s) this symptom, in general?** - By not having the appropriate permissions.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the author already deleted the folder in question.

Comment: If I didn't have appropriate permissions, the cmd doesn't throw an access denied or something?  It just pretends to delete it without doing anything?

Comment: @JohnnyBlack - I recently wrote an answer here https://superuser.com/questions/1462176/two-files-will-not-delete-from-hdd/1462392#1462392 that resolved this sort of problem for someone else. Give that solution a try as it's usually always successful for me assuming the issue doesn't have something to do with the **further notable items** section.

Comment: Thanks for that answer!  I'm fairly certain that the "in use" under your further notable items was the culprit.  That explains what I was seeing.

Answer (score 7):

#### If I didn't have appropriate permissions, the cmd doesn't throw an access denied or something?

That's not how `del` is designed to work. If files **are** deleted, then `del` will inform you. If no files are deleted then `del` is silent or will display an error message (for example "Access is denied.").

> Normally DEL will display a list of the files deleted, if Command Extensions are disabled; it will instead display a list of any files it cannot find.

Source [Del - Delete Files - Windows CMD - SS64.com](https://ss64.com/nt/del.html)

If no files are deleted and you do not have the appropriate permissions to remove them an error message will be displayed:

```
F:\test\foo>del C:\Windows\notepad.exe
C:\Windows\notepad.exe
Access is denied.
```

---

#### I'd expect some output indicating the directory wasn't deleted.

If you use `del` with a directory name then it will delete the files **in the directory**. The directory specified is **not** deleted.

> If a folder name is given instead of a file, all files in the folder will be deleted, but the folder itself will not be removed.

Source [Del - Delete Files - Windows CMD - SS64.com](https://ss64.com/nt/del.html)

To delete both directories **and** the files and subdirectories use `rd` (an alias for `rmdir`):

> **Remove (or Delete) a Directory.**
>
> Syntax
>
> ```
> RD pathname
> RD /S pathname
> RD /S /Q pathname
> ```
>
> `/S` : Delete all files and subfolders in addition to the folder
>   itself. Use this to remove an entire folder tree.

Source - [RD - Remove Directory - Windows CMD - SS64.com](https://ss64.com/nt/rd.html)

Comment: Well, `del C:\Windows\notepad.exe` is definitely not silent here.

Comment: @grawity Answer updated

Answer (score 5):

`del` will delete all contents, but (even with `/f` or `/s`) it never removes the directories themselves; that's just how it was written.

Use `rmdir /s` instead:

```
rd/s/q node_modules
```

Comment: when I cd into the directory, all the files are still there