# UwfServicingMasterScript can not be edited due to missing permissions

Tags: windows, windows-10, permissions, uwf, uwfmgr

I am using the optional Windows 10 feature "Unified Write Filter" (uwfmgr.exe) to protect kiosk machines from unwanted changes.
Now in order to deploy custom updates, it includes a Servicing User under which changes to the protected volumes can be performed.

To execute these custom updates, the script at `C:\Windows\system32\UwfServicingMasterScript.cmd` is supposed to be edited. ([official Documentation](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/customize/enterprise/uwf-apply-oem-updates))

Now I am unable to edit this file since it is owned by the "TrustedInstaller" user for which not even Administrators have permissions.

[image]

What am I missing here?
Am I supposed to change the owner of this file?

Comment: Clamp, I'd suggest you "copy" the file  `UwfServicingMasterScript.cmd` to the desktop and edit that copy as desired. Then you may have to forcefully delete `C:\Windows\system32\UwfServicingMasterScript.cmd` using a similar syntax as [I wrote about here](https://superuser.com/questions/1462176/two-files-will-not-delete-from-hdd/1462392#1462392) if you have trouble deleting it but adjust to not be for folders and recursively deleting all files as mentioned there. You might have to get forceful to get it to delete, and then you copy the new file from the desktop to `C:\Windows\system32`. Done!

Answer (score 0):

My own understanding of the subject is incomplete, but I believe that you are
supposed to use a certain procedure when doing these kind of updates,
and specifically you are not supposed to take ownership of Windows files.

The process is better described in the article
[Overview of Microsoft UWF (Unified Write Filter)](https://www.recastsoftware.com/blog/unified-write-filter-basic-overview),
of which here is a short summary:

- With UWF enabled, create a new text file, say `C:\TestPersist`
- Add it to UWF with the command:

  ```
    uwfmgr file add-exclusion c:\testpersist
  ```
- Enable UWF with the command : `uwfmgr filter enable`
- To check UWF settings use : `uwfmgr.exe get-config`

References:

- Microsoft [Service UWF-protected devices](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/customize/enterprise/service-uwf-protected-devices)
- Microsoft [Use the Unified Write Filter (UWF) feature](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/customize/enterprise/uwf-turnonuwf)
- [UWF Servicing.pdf](https://www.10zig.com/download_file/view/506)

Note: You might find useful the new Windows 10 feature of
[Windows Sandbox](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/windows-kernel-internals/windows-sandbox/ba-p/301849).

Comment: thanks for your answer. but my specific problem is about not being able to edit the UwfServicingMasterScript and not the generic useage of uwfmgr

Comment: You are not supposed to edit it, which is why Microsoft locked it so well. You're supposed to use the `add-exclusion` verb. Taking ownership is possible, but causes problems later on.

Comment: If you follow the link I posted, Microsoft says quote `you can modify the UPDATE_SUCCESS block of UWF master servicing script` . I have to rollout driver updates for which I do not know which files or registry keys are affected. So exclusions or direct commits are not an option for me.

Comment: If you insist: The subject of safely taking ownership and giving it back once finished, I once covered in [this answer](https://superuser.com/a/1365110/8672), so read it carefully. The "icacls /restore" ownership part may possibly not work for the TrustedInstaller account, and in that case the only repair solution would be a repair install of Windows. If you intend going this way, let me know how it ended.

Answer (score 0):

I may be a little late to the party, but I just found this post, because I ran into the same problems.

With the use of @vomit-it-chunky-mess-style their comment I came to the following C# code, which works for replacing the cmd file with my own.
Hopefully this helps the next person to land here.

```
using System.Diagnostics;

var masterScriptLocation = @"C:\Windows\System32\UwfServicingMasterScript.cmd";
var newMasterScript = 
    """
    REM servicing of the device with UWF installed. The script will
    REM call UWF manager application to update the system with the
    REM latest available updates.
    REM The script will detect whether the update operation
    REM ended successfully or requires a reboot.
    REM
    REM The script will change the "SERVICING" state of the device
    REM only when the update operation results in a "SUCCESS".
    REM A state change of the device requires a reboot.
    REM
    REM If the update operation requires a "REBOOT" the script will
    REM reboot device without changing the "SERVICING" state. The
    REM Will then run again on the following reboot until
    REM the update operation either return a "SUCCESS" or a "ERROR"
    REM
    REM Any third-party script that needs to run before the state
    REM change should run in the UPDATE_SUCCESS block
    REM
    REM Environment :
    REM It is expected that UWF is turned "OFF", "SERVICING" mode
    REM enabled and all other preconditions
    REM for servicing are in place.
    REM
    REM
    REM
    
    
    echo UpdateAgent starting.
    uwfmgr servicing update-windows
    if ERRORLEVEL 3010 goto UPDATE_REBOOT
    if ERRORLEVEL 0 goto UPDATE_SUCCESS
    echo UpdateAgent returned error =%ERRORLEVEL%
    
    :UPDATE_ERROR
    uwfmgr servicing disable
    echo Restarting system
    goto UPDATE_EXIT
    
    :UPDATE_REBOOT
    echo UpdateAgent requires a reboot.
    echo UpdateAgent restarting system
    goto UPDATE_EXIT
    
    :UPDATE_SUCCESS
    echo UpdateAgent returned success.
    REM
    REM echo UpdateAgent executing OEM script
    REM OEM can call their custom scripts
    REM at this point through a "call".
    REM
    REM The OEM script should hand control
    REM back to this script once it is done.
    REM
    REM Any error recovery for OEM script
    REM should be handled outside of this script
    REM post a reboot.
    REM
    uwfmgr servicing disable
    echo Restarting system
    goto UPDATE_EXIT
    
    :UPDATE_EXIT
    echo UpdateAgent exiting.
    shutdown -r -t 5
    EXIT /B
    """;

using (Process myProcess = new())
{
    myProcess.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
    myProcess.StartInfo.FileName = "takeown.exe";
    myProcess.StartInfo.Arguments = $"""/a /f "{masterScriptLocation}" """;
    myProcess.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
    myProcess.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
    myProcess.Start();
    myProcess.WaitForExit();
    string output = myProcess.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd();
    Console.WriteLine(output);
}

using (Process myProcess = new())
{
    myProcess.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
    myProcess.StartInfo.FileName = "icacls";
    myProcess.StartInfo.Arguments = $""" "{masterScriptLocation}" /grant everyone:F /t""";
    myProcess.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
    myProcess.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
    myProcess.Start();
    myProcess.WaitForExit();
    string output = myProcess.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd();
    Console.WriteLine(output);
}

File.Delete(masterScriptLocation);

File.WriteAllText(masterScriptLocation,newMasterScript);
```