# Windows Administrator cannot access data drive

Tags: windows, security, permissions, file-permissions

I recently installed a second drive into the PC running Windows 10 Pro. The drive is used for data.  I usually work as a non-admin user.  I have a couple of top-level folders on that drive (D:) and use read/write data in those folders.

I now needed to create another top-level folder (say, D:\new-folder).  As the non-admin user I couldn't do it.  When I checked permission on the top-level drive, I can see that my non-admin user only has read/execute permission on the drive.

So I logged in as the local Administrator account - but I can't even read the top level drive.  I can't even see the used space on it.  As soon as I try to click on it in explorer, I get "Access denied".

If I start powershell or command prompt "run as admin" and attempt to cd into drive D:, I get "access denied" error.

I can probably copy all the data out and then re-format the drive, but there's over a terabyte of data and I don't have anywhere to copy it to.  I cannot afford to loose this data at the moment. As a local administrator, no matter what I do, I always get "Access denied".  This applies to `takeown`, `get-acl`, `set-acl`, etc.

When I log in as a non-admin user, I can view the content of the drive and I can view the current permissions on the drive, which include "Full control" for members of the "Aministrators" group.

How can I get the Administrator to access the drive and make the relevant changes?  Note that I have full administrator access to the PC and can make any changes I need.

*UPDATE:* per suggestion from another place, here's the output of get-acl:

```
Owner          : NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM
AccessToString : NT AUTHORITY\Authenticated Users Allow  -536805376
                 NT AUTHORITY\Authenticated Users Allow  Modify, Synchronize
                 NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM Allow  FullControl
                 NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM Allow  268435456
                 BUILTIN\Administrators Allow  268435456
                 BUILTIN\Administrators Allow  FullControl
                 BUILTIN\Users Allow  ReadAndExecute, Synchronize
                 BUILTIN\Users Allow  -1610612736
```

Comment: @PimpJuiceIT Thanks.  Both as admin and non-admin, I get "Access denied" for the root of drive D: As non-admin, it does changes some of the files under D: but not all.  As admin, it doesn't even try, because it can't read the content of D:

Comment: So command elevated as administrator command line on either of those accounts, what happens if you run `takeown /a /r /d Y /f "D:\"`?

Comment: @PimpJuiceIT Comes back with _ERROR: Access is denied._ - and nothing else

Comment: That’s interesting. I would also try `chkdsk D: /f` from an admin command prompt.

Comment: Both admin and not admin chkdsk result in the same error: _Access Denied as you do not have sufficient privileges_

Comment: Furthermore, see the section I wrote about here labeled "**Further Notable Items**": https://superuser.com/questions/1462176/two-files-will-not-delete-from-hdd/1462392#1462392 ... Something is either corrupt file system wise or something has something inuse/locked and thus that's what's up.

Comment: I suspect that something is off with the fildsystem.  Running `takeown /F D:\` as user _nt authority\system_ results in the same message "Access is denied"

Comment: Linux won't help, as the disk is encrypted with bitlocker

Comment: Maybe bitlocker has something to do with it based on how you configured the drive encryption, etc. Perhaps you can bitlocker decrypt, reboot, and then try to take ownership. I guess you tried manually taking ownership per something like this it does not work either.... https://www.isumsoft.com/windows-10/take-ownership-of-a-file-folder-drive.html

Comment: @AleksG - You should disable BitLocker protection, see if the problem remains, and then enable BitLocker protection.  What you describe is abnormal.  **The default permissions on an external non-system drive is universal read/write access. The fact you are getting an access denied message indicates sever file system corruption.**

Comment: @Ramhound it isn't an external drive. It's a second internal drive

Comment: Can you add the output of `whoami /groups` to your question. When logged in as the administrator.

Comment: @AleksG - What I said applies to non-system drives unless you specifically changed it.  I still suspect file system corruption.