# How to delete folder named with three dots on Windows?

Tags: windows, windows-explorer

I meet a weird thing =)

There is a folder named with three dots, and that folder self-referencing itself, so I can go inside forever:
[image]

and that shown from `cmd` with `dir`:
[image]

I can't delete that folder or parents, I assume, because of that self-reference, how to cope with that?

Comment: Create a small virtual HDD and mount it within Windows. Cut and paste the root folder onto the mounted drive then format the drive

Comment: What is the top directory that hold the first `...`? Can you create another folder and move the `...` to that folder?

Comment: Those look like three dots, not commas. I assume these were created from a different file system and then copied to or mounted onto Windows NTFS. When I try create a folder name via UI in Windows 10, it states folder path is too long even right at root of an NTFS partition with the name `...`. It's probably affected by Windows API and/or NTFS character limitations but try suggested command line for deletion.  See answer here for more detail and other command solutions: https://superuser.com/questions/1462176/two-files-will-not-delete-from-hdd/1462392#1462392

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may be able to force delete the folders by deleting the top folder containing the `...`. Use in **ADMIN command prompt**:

`RMDIR /S /Q [Full Path To Top Folder Containing First ...]`

This has worked for me in the past when I get a folder that won't delete through normal means. With that said, I haven't experienced this specific event.

Comment: worked for me, when typed that command, the dir was not deleted, instead the error was shown `The directory is not empty.`, however, also, the target directory became clean. After I has deleted that as normal directory.

Comment: Thanks! It worked for me from cmd.exe but not from the PowerShell.